# Reorder link using hash

Tags: magento-1.8, addtocart, security

I'm working on a reorder-module that will allow my customers to:
a) Click a link i email
b) Click a link in order history

What will happend next is that:
1) Delete all items currently in cart
2) Add the items based on the order ID provided

As I plan to add email reminders etc I need this option to work if the user is not logged in as well. Hence I need to add like increment ID to the actual link. However, I dont want customers to randomaly just change the increment ID I need to come up with something.

So my thoughts so far of possible approaches:

a) Hash the increment_id together with some salt (public, not user specific) in the link like **www.mydomain,com/index.php/myReOrderModule/.../HASH_VALUE***
On the downside, I need to first, in the module, loop through all increment_ids and check against the hash-value to find a match.

b) Add both the increment_id and the hash-value to the link. Like:
 **www.mydomain,com/index.php/myReOrderModule/.../INCREMENT_ID/HASH_VALUE***
In this case all I need to to check is **INCREMENT_ID** add salt and check it against hash-value

So my questions:

1) Which option is to prefer (their might be others as well?)

2) Is this method "safe" enough to also prefill the cart with shipping details from previous order?

Answer (score 3):

Nice question :-)

**1) Which option is to prefer (their might be others as well?)**

I would go with option a). Do not include the INCREMENT_ID at all in the url, that is a potential leak for a brute force attack.

You might be interested to have a look how the unique URLs are implemented for the downloadable products as inspiration.

**2) Is this method "safe" enough to also prefill the cart with shipping details from previous order?**

If you managed to relate the HASH_VALUE to a specific order, please do also check if that specific order is related to the customer currently logged in.
If both requirements can be fulfilled (existing order that can be matched to the HASH_VALUE and it's the current customers order) I think you are fine to continue with your process.

Comment: Thanks Anna, in regards to 2) I want this option to work if the user compeleted the order as guest for instance. SO they dont need to be logged in. By doing so I can use it in emails etc.